# Visual Studio Code Toggle Open Files in Grid View

Tags: visual-studio-code

The latest VS Code supports the Grid Layout

In the normal view if you have multiple files open they appear in tabs at the top. You can switch between this tabs by Holding down CTRL + TAB.

How can I do the same in the new Grid Layout?

What I know so far:

-It looks like when you use the Grid Layout the files get split up in to groups.
Once you have a new group you can add additional open files to that group and you have multiple tabs within that group and you can toggle between them with the CTRL + TAB.

-I have found that using CTRL + # (Where # is the group number) toggles you to that group
--Although this is close, it is not the same as the Ctrl + Tab

Comment: need to disable this "feature" asap xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a *"Focus Next Editor Group"* action, I think this is what you are looking for. It has no keyboard shortcut set by default, you can assign one with these steps:

1. Open [Keyboard Shortcuts Editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) by pressing `CTRL+Shift+P` and searching for *"Keyboard Shortcuts"*
2. Search for *"Focus Next Editor Group"*
3. Click on "+" button on its left side
4. Press the shortcut, then press `ENTER` to save it

Comment: Indeed, this does exactly what I was looking for. It toggles between the "groups" as it would do a tab. You nailed it!